# Выравнивание camel routes на Java DSL в intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, плагин, camel

Поискал по интернетам и не нашёл никаких плагинов для `intellij-idea` которые будут выравнивать camel rout'ы в "правильную" иерархию, как например делает с обычным java кодом стандартный `ctrl+alt+l`.

Может кто-нибудь знает/видел что то подобное?

Сейчас так:

```
public void configure() {

    // here is a sample which processes the input files
    // (leaving them in place - see the 'noop' flag)
    // then performs content based routing on the message using XPath
    from("file:src/data?noop=true")
            .choice()
            .when(xpath("/person/city = 'London'"))
            .log("UK message")
            .to("file:target/messages/uk")
            .otherwise()
            .log("Other message")
            .to("file:target/messages/others");
}
```

А хочу вот так:

```
public void configure() {

    // here is a sample which processes the input files
    // (leaving them in place - see the 'noop' flag)
    // then performs content based routing on the message using XPath
    from("file:src/data?noop=true")
        .choice()
            .when(xpath("/person/city = 'London'"))
                .log("UK message")
                .to("file:target/messages/uk")
            .otherwise()
                .log("Other message")
                .to("file:target/messages/others");
}
```

Comment: Думаю можно в службе поддержки спросить. Хотя на мой взгляд такого плагина нет. Но вы можете его написать.

Comment: @Михаил Кетов Не нужны никакие плагины для этих целей. В IDEA все замечательно настраивается. Кликаем: Ctrl + Alt + S, затем Editor, затем Code Style и здесь кликаем Java.  [Подробнее...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html)

Comment: @Владимир ТС хочешь, что бы у определенных вызовов отступ был отличным от всех остальных.

Comment: @Михаил Кетов Кстати и убери картинки.